# Why is 'I saw her cry' correct, but 'I saw her cried' isn't?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

Why is

> I saw her **cry**.

correct but

> I saw her **cried**.

is not?

Answer (score 6):

The construction is **passive,** so it won't really work with an intransitive verb. Let's change the verb *cry* to an obviously transitive verb, say *watch*:

> - I saw her watch [something].
> - I saw her watched.

The first one says that you saw her watch something. She was looking at it intently.

The second one says that you saw her *being watched.* Someone else was looking at her intently.

You can't use this construction with an intransitive verb like *cry,* because intransitive verbs can't be passivised. (That is, *cry* in this case is intransitive because *she* can't *be cried.*)

Comment: This room was slept in/cried in by George Washington. See my ELU query and the great answer: [Is “This room was slept in by Milton” grammatical even though ‘sleep’ is an intransitive verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369477/is-this-room-was-slept-in-by-milton-grammatical-even-though-sleep-is-an-intr) @Andrew

Comment: Passivation with "by" is a standard form of showing the actual subject of the transitive verb. Note though that your sentence has a different structure to "I saw her watched".

Answer (score 2):

The verb construction after verbs of perception (to see, watch, hear etc) is verb + object + bare infinitive or present participle as in

- I saw the man/him climb/climbing over the wall of the garden.
- I heard the bus/it come/coming.

If you replace "come/coming" by "came" that is considered wrong grammar. Maybe you think "I heard (that) the bus came" would be logical, too. Maybe. But the usual construction is 2000 years old and was a standard construction in Latin. And this construction is the preferred one after verbs of perception.

Comment: Note that with a transitive verb the past participle is acceptable, too: "I saw the man arrested".

Comment: Right. But I think that's a pattern the poster did not have in mind.

Comment: Quite so; but it's a pattern that may have given rise to OP's suggestion of "saw her cried", and it might be of value to explain the difference.

Comment: *I heard the bus came* is grammatical and natural.